# No memory for installing packages and software

Tags: lubuntu, ram

I recently installed Lubuntu 16.04 on a laptop, removing everything (it had a few partition issues) and re-creating disk partitions from scratch.
However, the system is not able to install any new software or package, because it says it has:

```
No free space. The upgrade needs a total of 1.221 M free space on disk
'/'. Please free at least an additional 1.150 M of disk space on '/'.
Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations
using 'sudo apt-get clean
```

I install Ubuntu many times but I never had this issue. The laptop should have around 900Gb of free memory on the partition. Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks,

Jacopo Cerri

Comment: Please post output of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1117690/edit) your original question above and copy and paste the new information such as the output of `df -h`. Then format the pasted output as **code** using the **{ }** icon above the question edit window.

Comment: U can delete the old kernel and other un necessary packages. If problem still persist kindly say it in comment

Comment: I already tried to remove old packages with 'sudo-apt get clean' and nothing changes. However, it is pointless, as the laptop should have been completely re-partitioned. There is only Lubuntu on it.

Comment: I might try to remove the old kernel, but I do not know whether there would be one. Before the laptop had Windows10. I was thinking about an issue with memory partitioning, but I cannot really understand where the problem might be.